# Site builded with empty folder (and working)

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I Have websites in cpanel, but someones are builded by an empty folder

[image]

This one is not empty and I can see the wordpress folders.

[image]

But this folder for example is empty, but I have a website working in this folder.

[image]

I try to see if these folder are privates, but they aren't

I check if my user is the onwer (and he is)

I try to compress the folder in an attempt to see the subfolders.

(By the way, these folders has a .htaccess file and i don't know what it is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked in the .htaccess file for redirection, the file might be redirecting requests to another folder or directory.
.htaccess files can be used to configure rewrite rules and redirects in Apache.
Some common uses are:

Redirect from an old URL to a new URL
Redirect a URL to a folder/file on the same server
Redirect a URL to an entirely different domain
Block access to certain files or folders
Enable URL rewriting to make URLs more SEO-friendly

Comment: How is the redirect commnand in htacess? The htacess in subfolders where is empty is inherinting parent rules. I am trying to find the redirect. Btw, thanks ;)

Comment: You are right. Htacess was redirecting to another folder in another server, not in my cpanel